# SQL Server how to use alias in the same query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I would write my query in this way but

```
SELECT 
     TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity - ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0)  QuantityDifference
     ,IIF((QuantityDifference > 0), QuantityDifference, 0) QuantityDifferencePositive
FROM [TempInventoryComparisonReal]
LEFT JOIN [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual] 
ON ([TempInventoryComparisonReal].ItemsCoresId = [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].ItemsCoresId 
AND [TempInventoryComparisonReal].Dimensions1Id=[TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].Dimensions1Id
AND [TempInventoryComparisonReal].Dimensions2Id=[TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].Dimensions2Id
AND [TempInventoryComparisonReal].SerialNumber=[TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].SerialNumber)
```

but sql server can't see the alias

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InventoryComparisonRealView, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 37]
Invalid column name 'QuantityDifference'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InventoryComparisonRealView, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 37]
Invalid column name 'QuantityDifference'.
```

I must repeat the formula and the query become not easy to read!

```
,ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0) QuantityVirtual
,IIF((ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0) - TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity)>0, (ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0) - TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity), 0) QuantityDifferencePositive
,IIF((ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0) - TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity)<0,(ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0) - TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity) , 0) QuantityDifferenceNegative
```

Comment: It is also really hard to read when you don't bother to format left in your post.

Comment: Simply use this as subquery or use a cte ,can isolate code for better understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what A.van Esveld said:

```
SELECT QuantityDifference
    , IIF((QuantityDifference > 0), QuantityDifference, 0) QuantityDifferencePositive
FROM (
    select TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity - ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0) QuantityDifference
    from [TempInventoryComparisonReal]
    left join [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual] on (
            [TempInventoryComparisonReal].ItemsCoresId = [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].ItemsCoresId
            and [TempInventoryComparisonReal].Dimensions1Id = [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].Dimensions1Id
            and [TempInventoryComparisonReal].Dimensions2Id = [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].Dimensions2Id
            and [TempInventoryComparisonReal].SerialNumber = [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].SerialNumber
            )
) R
```

Comment: @Evilripper If you notice a difference in performance i would be very surprised.

Answer (score 2):

What I tend to do when I really want to use the alias to keep it readable is put it into a subquery, that way you can use the alias in the select.

Comment: @Evilripper It's so little that you won't ever notice it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subquery.

```
    SELECT  IIF((QuantityDifference > 0), QuantityDifference, 0) QuantityDifferencePositive 
FROM    (           
            SELECT 
                     TempInventoryComparisonReal.Quantity - ISNULL([TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].[Quantity], 0)  QuantityDifference     
                FROM [TempInventoryComparisonReal]
                LEFT JOIN [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual] 
                ON ([TempInventoryComparisonReal].ItemsCoresId = [TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].ItemsCoresId 
                AND [TempInventoryComparisonReal].Dimensions1Id=[TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].Dimensions1Id
                AND [TempInventoryComparisonReal].Dimensions2Id=[TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].Dimensions2Id
                AND [TempInventoryComparisonReal].SerialNumber=[TempInventoryComparisonVirtual].SerialNumber)
        ) AS X
```

Answer (score 1):

You must repeat the formula, query analyzer take care of it.

```
SELECT (Field1 - Field2) QtyDiff,
       IIF((Field1 - Field2) > 0, (Field1 - Field2), 0) QtyDiffPositive
```